# Stop swagger from loading as startup page in ASP.net Core 5 MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, visual-studio-2019, swagger-ui

I'm building an ASP.net Core 5 MVC application integrated with Swagger.
I use Nuget [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger Version 6.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swagger/)

It is the latest up to the date of writting this post.
Now I have 2 issues:

1. Swagger always load its page as start up page whatever
   configuration I do in the startup.cs file. The application always starts from: http://localhost:port/index.html (I don't know from where this routing happens??!!)
2. I want to start up the
   application from http://www.url.com/home/index then when the user
   type http://www.url.com/swagger the swagger page starts to be displayed.

Here is how I configured my startup.cs, if anyone can advise what is wrong with my configuration:

```
using MYAPIDataModels.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MYAPIServer.Models.Swagger;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Reflection;
using MYAPIServer.Data;

namespace MYAPIDataModels
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IMYAPIServerConnector, MYAPIServerConnector>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
                    //options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 256;
                });

        // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQqsII9iyPk

        services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            // https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2019/11/aspnet-core-web-api-versioning.html
            // to allow accessing controllers with no versioning (like Home or Login).
            //options.UseApiBehavior = false;
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);

            // https://www.thecodebuzz.com/api-versioning-in-asp-net-core-with-examples/
            //options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
            options.ApiVersionReader = new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("v");
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
                {

                    /* https://dotnetthoughts.net/openapi-and-versioning-asp-net-core/
                    ** Following code to avoid swagger generation error
                    ** due to same method name in different versions.   */

                    options.ResolveConflictingActions(descriptions => descriptions.First());

                    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { 
                    Title = "MYAPI API",
                    Description  = "MYAPI Web API",
                    Version = "v1"
                    });

                    options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = "MYAPI API",
                        Description = "MYAPI Web API",
                        Version = "v2"
                    });

                    // https://dev.to/htissink/versioning-asp-net-core-apis-with-swashbuckle-making-space-potatoes-v-x-x-x-3po7
                    // https://dev.to/codeswayslay/comment/paff

                    options.DocInclusionPredicate((version, desc) =>
                    {
                        if (!desc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
                            return false;

                        var versions = methodInfo.DeclaringType
                        .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                        .OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>()
                        .SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions);

                        var maps = methodInfo
                        .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                        .OfType<MapToApiVersionAttribute>()
                        .SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions)
                        .ToArray();

                        return versions.Any(ver => $"v{ver}" == version)
                        && (!maps.Any() || maps.Any(ver => $"v{ver}" == version));
                    });

                    options.OperationFilter<RemoveVersionFromParameter>();
                    options.DocumentFilter<ReplaceVersionWithExactValueInPath>();
                });

        services.AddDbContext<MYAPIServerContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MYAPIServerContext")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger for MYAPI Web API V1");
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Swagger for MYAPI Web API V2");
            options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            //endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            //endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try this: in `app.UseSwaggerUI` you'll want to change the `options.RoutePrefix = "swagger";` insead of the empty string.

Comment: I've tried this already, once I add the "swagger" as prefix, the application keeps startup with "https://localhost:port/index.html" with error 404, then if I added "swagger" manually to the url it loads the swagger UI.

Comment: What I want is the application starts normally by going to home/index then when I add swagger to the url it loads the ui

Comment: You're half way there with having "swagger" which will be required for your use case.  The other half is making your actual app's default be "home" on startup.  That can be done with launchsettings.json -- find your app and add `"launchUrl": "home"`.

Comment: ``` if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger for MYAPI Web API V1");
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Swagger for MYAPI Web API V2");
            options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });```  i think,it will works fine.

Comment: @BrettLee Can you please setup standard Web API .net core 5 application with the settings I provided then tell me the result?

Comment: @jimnkey when I used "launchUrl": "home", not "launchUrl": "home/index", it worked.

Comment: This is not needed app.UseSwaggerUI -- options.RouterPrefix = "swagger" as this is default path of swagger. You can then all in launchsettings.json "launchUrl": "swagger" and it will by default open swagger when run. thanks